# Select Multiple value from a table but group by one value

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select multiple values from two tables but i want to group by single value. I have tried using max(value) in select but max is returning the greatest one and not the exact one.

Here are my tables 
[image]

The result i need is something like this

```
Result : HeadQuarterId - A, PropertyName - Name1, Amount - 102
         HeadQuarterId - B, PropertyName - Name5, Amount - 30
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT  Headquarterid,Max(PropertyName),sum(Amount)  
FROM Table1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 B
ON A.Propetyid = B.PropertyId  
GROUP BY Headquarterid
```

Here i have used Left Outer Join so that i will get all the data from left table even it is not available in right table.

Also i cannot use A.HeadquarterID = A.PropertyId in where condition  since i have other dependency in that table. Please suggest someother way to achieve this result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve... where does the 101 in your example come from? What exactly is the expected result? Your tables seem to have a 1:1 relationship via propertyid - so I'd expect the result 46 for headquarter A

Comment: @Tyron78 From looking at the question, I believe 101 is the sum of all the `Amount` in table 2

Comment: @Tyron78 It is the sum of amount column

Comment: @bala3569 yes, I thought so - but which value did you expect? Since Headquarter A has only Property ID A, the sum is not correct, right?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Edit the question add more sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: @Tyron78 I have changed the values in HeadQuarterid column. Please check now

Comment: @YogeshSharma Sure i will add more sample data

Comment: @bala3569 so what is the logic in your expected result, that you want the first property for A but the last property for B?

Comment: @Tyron78 There can be many Headquarter under a Property and Headquarter itself is a property.. so i need Headquarterid  and its name  and sum of amount under that Headquarter

Comment: @bala3569 but if HeadquarteName is a property, then it has to be distiguishable by something so that you can tell Headquartename from other properties, no? In your example: How do you identify name1 and name5 as Headquartename?

Comment: @Tyron78 but both Headquarterid and Propertyid are same so the propertyname of the Property is the propertyname of the headquarter

Comment: @bala3569 then in your example name4 should be the headquartename since its propertyid matches the headquarteid. However, you might try something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bf66/10/2

Comment: @Tyron78 Name5 is the correct propertyname since both Headquarterid and Propertyid are same as B

Comment: @bala3569 ah, I see... have a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bf66/13/2

Comment: @bala3569 so, did this query work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data you want *window* function :

```
select distinct t1.HeadQuarterId, 
       max(t1.PropertyName) over (partition by t1.HeadQuarterId) as PropertyName,
       sum(t2.amount) over (partition by t1.HeadQuarterId) as amount
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t2.PropertyId = t1.PropertyId;
```

Comment: @bala3569 . . . You keep changing the sample data.  Try the answer now.

Comment: It should be Name1 instead of Name3

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand.  You want the headquarters with the maximum value, which happens to be `A`.  If so:

```
select t1.*, sum(t2.amount) over () as total
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t2.PropertyId = t1.PropertyId
order by t2.amount desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  Not all databases support `fetch first`.  It might be spelled `limit` or use `select top (1)` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to get the headquartename per ID in a cte / subquery, then join it again to T1 and left join T1 to T2 in a second cte / subquery. This way you can calculate your sums basing on a single group:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.ID = t1.PROPERTYID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn, t1.ID, t1.Name
  FROM t1
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT c.name cName, t1.*, t2.Value
  FROM t1
  INNER JOIN cte c ON c.ID = t1.ID AND c.rn = 1
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Propertyid = t2.propertyid
)
SELECT c2.id, c2.cname, sum(c2.value) value
  FROM cte2 c2
  GROUP BY c2.id, c2.cname
```

See SQLFiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bf66/13/2

Of course you can build the first cte without the row_number only by using the `WHERE ID = PROPERTYID` - matter of taste I'd say...

Answer (score 0):

This provided the result i expected.

```
SELECT HQTRS1 AS headId,Max(LLORD1) AS headName, sum(Amount) AS amount  
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT HeadQuarterId AS HQTRS1, PropertyName AS LLORD1 FROM Table_1 WHERE HeadQuarterId = PropertyId) AS temp
        INNER JOIN Table_1 AS A ON A.HeadQuarterId  = temp.HQTRS1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 B
        ON B.PropertyId = A.PropertyId
        GROUP BY HQTRS1
```